# Proof of closure of center of a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Main Question: Let $G$ be a group and $g∈G$. Show that $Z(G)={\{x∈G: gx=xg\ \text{for all}\ g∈G}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. This subgroup is called the center of $G$.

It just remained for me to show closure of $Z$. If $x_1, x_2∈Z(G)$ then $g_1x_1=x_1g_1$ and $g_2x_2=x_2g_2$ for some $g_1∈G$ and $g_2∈G$. Let $g_1=g_2$ then we are done. What if supposing $g_1\ne g_2$, which we are allowed to consider?

Thank you.

Comment: The statement "for some $g_1\in G$ and $g_2\in G$" is not correct. Rather it should be by definition: $x_1g=gx_1$ for all $g\in G$ and also $x_2g=gx_2$ for all $g\in G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $a,b\in Z(G)$ then $$(ab)g=a(bg)=a(gb)=(ag)b=g(ab)$$

for all $g\in G$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y\in Z(G)$, then $xg=gx,yg=gy\;\forall g\in G$

Now, \begin{align}
(xy)g&=x(yg)&\quad\text{Since G is a group}\\
&=x(gy)&\quad \text{Since $y\in Z(G)$}\\
&=(xg)y&\quad\text{again since G is a group}\\
&=g(xy)&\quad \text{Since $x\in Z(G)$, G is group}\\
\end{align}
 So, $xy\in Z(G)$.